# R Beta function - relative y scale

Tags: r, scale

I am having trouble understanding the Beta function in R. I want the y scale to display a relative value in percent (0->1). How do I achive this with the graph having the same form?

```
x = seq(0,1,0.001)
plot(x,dbeta(x,10,40), type="l", col="red", xlab="time", ylab="frequency")
```

Comment: What do you mean "display a relative value in percent (0->1)"? You're plotting the beta density right now.

Comment: The y axis should display relative values from 0 to 1 (0% to 100%).

Comment: Are you looking for the distribution function (the integral of the density), or do you want to normalize the density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `beta` density, normalized so the maximum value is 1. This could be accomplished with:

```
x = seq(0,1,0.001)
density = dbeta(x, 10, 40)
plot(x, density/max(density), type="l", col="red", xlab="time", ylab="frequency")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure you looked the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Beta.html) at the value page perhaps there is what you are looking for :

> *dbeta* gives the density, *pbeta* the distribution function, *qbeta* the quantile function, and *rbeta* generates random deviates.

I think you want to plot the pbeta

Comment: Hm.
x is supposed to be "time in hours" and y should be "relative frequency".
The statement of the graph should be "most incidents (7) take about 0.2 hours"